# rosbag of extrinsic calibration

Tags: calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_launch/Tutorials/ExtrinsicCalibration

my system is ubuntu11.10,installed with ROS( electric) and openni_kinect.

Use rosbag to record 10 seconds of RGB data to rgb.bag:

rosbag record --limit=300 -O rgb /camera/rgb/image_rect /camera/rgb/camera_info

terminal display

[ INFO] [1340799943.911159328]: Subscribing to camera/rgb/image_raw

[ INFO] [1340799943.913291068]: Subscribing to camera/rgb/camera_info

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'

what():  basic_string::erase

Aborted

I dont know what to do.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37374/rosbag-of-extrinsic-calibration/) by [rosmaker](https://answers.ros.org/users/2491/rosmaker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2012-06-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
Try changing the command line to:

rosbag record --limit=300 -O rgb.bag /camera/rgb/image_rect /camera/rgb/camera_info

Worked for me :)

Cheers,
Tom

---

Originally posted by [Smot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2736/smot/) with karma: 61 on 2012-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0